# How to import react-bootstrap classes globally in my react project?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm working on ReactJS web app using react-bootstrap for styling
like

```
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
```

in each component, How can I use it globally so I don't need to declare in each component.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to use the component you need to import it if you don't want to use component just use bootstrap.css and js and use plain html instead of component

Comment: @DhavalPatel you mean i need to include it in every component where i have to use this classes isn't any reusable-way i'm a beginner

Comment: let me create and example for you

Comment: sure it will more helpful for me

Comment: I think there is no way. You need to import it wherever you want to use it.

Comment: yes i need to import every where according to react-bootstrap document

Comment: @RahulTrlIt : I have added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import {Container, Row, Col, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Comment: I used this in app.js but getting error as Container, Col ,Row not found error in my component

Answer (score 0):

You need to import it and that's how its design like if you want to reuse the think you need to export it and import it in your case yes we can make it more readable and maintainable using index.js file.

You have a folder at root level which is `BootstrapComponent` and in that folder index.js file contain below-mentioned export like , all your require component will be exported once.

```
export  { Button, Alert  } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

you can use it in your component like

```
import { Button, Alert } from './BootstrapComponent';
```

Please check here for code [Demo Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-htyphs)

Comment: Hi @dhaval component based structure seem more cleaner and easy to understand. Thanks

Comment: Yes, here you are just exporting all the required component from bootstrap and use it in your apps so you just need to use 'BootstrapComponent' instead of everywhere importing from bootstrap